# Terraform - Enable OIDC on HashiCorp Vault child namespace

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, namespaces, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

I am able to provision an OIDC auth method on a HashiCorp vault Root namespace, using the below Terraform resource block.

```
resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend" "oidc" {
    description = "Azure Authentication with OIDC"
    oidc_discovery_url      = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${var.tenant_id}/v2.0"
    path                    = "oidc"
    type                    = "oidc"
    oidc_client_id          = var.client_id
    oidc_client_secret      = var.client_secret
    default_role            = "reader"
    provider_config = {
        provider = "azure"
        fetch_groups = true
        fetch_user_info = true
        groups_recurse_max_depth = 1
    }
}
```

Problem is, the OIDC auth method in this instance gets enabled on the Root namespace. What I would however like to do is enable it on a child namespace, which is possible when using the Vault CLI as depicted below.

```
vault auth enable -namespace=education/training oidc
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Terraform?

Comment: Does this help: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/resources/jwt_auth_backend#namespace_in_state?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create that by first terraform importing/creating the namespace with:

```
resource "vault_namespace" "child_namespace" {
path      = "child_namespace"
}
```

Take into account that in the case of the previous example my root namesapce was declared in my provider.tf file (or environmental variable)

I later called the path of the newly created child namespace in the resource block for the auth method:

(Using your same example)

```
resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend" "oidc" {
description = "Azure Authentication with OIDC"
oidc_discovery_url      = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${var.tenant_id}/v2.0"
path                    = "oidc"
type                    = "oidc"
oidc_client_id          = var.client_id
oidc_client_secret      = var.client_secret
*namespace             = vault_namespace.child_namespace.path*
default_role            = "reader"
provider_config = {
    provider = "azure"
    fetch_groups = true
    fetch_user_info = true
    groups_recurse_max_depth = 1
}
}
```

For more information check: [Codify Management of Vault Enterprise Using Terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/operations/codify-mgmt-enterprise)